# Python to extract data from a file when particular string is found

Tags: python

I am trying to extract (LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_RECVD_SIGCHLD) from the PUT_LOG tag whenever PUT_LOG tag is found i just want to extract information within that and put it into the another file.

Please find the code snippet from where want to extract information...

```
PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD,1,STRING, cmd);
PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD,1,STRING, cmd);
PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED,1, STRING, cmd);
enter code here

my out put should be like this 

LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD
LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR
CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED
```

I have written the code like this ..can you modify and give me the exctly code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


inFile = open("data.c")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")

buffer = []
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
    buffer.append(line)
    if line.startswith("PUT_LOG"):
        #---- starts a new data set
        if keepCurrentSet:
            outFile.write("".join(buffer))
        #now reset our state
        keepCurrentSet = False
        buffer = []
    elif line.startswith("LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG"):
        keepCurrentSet = True
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: It would be nice to see what you have tried. It's all *"you show me your's, I show you mine"* in SO :)

Comment: did u understand ..what is my expected result

Answer (score 0):

With an input-file `file_in`, and output-file `file_out` and a list `strings_to_filter` of strings to extract from the source-file given as arguments, `extract_lines(file_in, file_out, strings_to_filter)` will find, for any line in `file_in`, whatever the brackets of `PUT_LOG(...);` contain in-between, cross-checks it against the list `strings_to_filter` of accepted strings and appends it (into a new line) to `out.txt`:

```
import os
import re


def extract_lines(file_in, file_out, strings_to_filter):
    with open(file_in) as f_in, open(file_out, "a+") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            res = re.search("(PUT_LOG\()(.*)(\)\;)", line)
            if res is not None:
                i = 0
                for segment in res.group(2).split(","):
                    segment = segment.strip()
                    if segment in strings_to_filter and i < 2:
                        print(segment, file=f_out)
                        i += 1

extract_lines(
                  os.path.realpath("path/to/log_file.txt"),
                  os.path.realpath("path/to/output_file.txt"),
              [
               "CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD",
               "CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED",
               "CAPTIVE_RECVD_SIGCHLD",
               "LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG",
               "LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR"
               ]
              )
```

Comment: what is os then how can i intialsie plz give me the complte code

Comment: Sure. this should work out-of-the-box as long as you specify `file_in`, `file_out` and `search_string` according to your context. If you need to search for complex patterns instead of just a simple string, let me know, I can add it to the above example.

Comment: file_in = os.path.realpath("data.c")
file_out = os.path.realpath("output_file.txt")

search_string = "LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG"

with open(file_in, "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in.readlines():
        if search_string in line:
            with open(file_out, "a+") as f_out:
                f_out.write(line)

Comment: I have updated the code to match your problem a bit closer; it should do exactly what you need it to do now, if I understand your description correctly.

Comment: `for line in f_in.readlines()` would be simpler and more memory efficient as `for line in f_in`. Similarly, `open(file_in, "r")` is simpler as `open(file_in)`. Also you can easily avoid using global variables and pass them to `extract_line()`, which would show explicitly that its result depends on two parameters. Finally, you should not `write(…+'\r')`: the newline is incorrect: you should do `print >> f_out, segment`.

Comment: Good points EOL, sorry for the messy sketch. I will add your suggestions to my post for the sake of a clean solution.

Comment: I want to extract only this LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD from the PUT_LOG tag..and dump to another file the reslut

Comment: i tried with the above code ..m getting exception like                        import os
import re

file_in = os.path.realpath("data.c")
file_out = os.path.realpath("output_file.txt")


def extract_lines():
    with open(file_in, "r") as f_in:
        for line in f_in.readlines():
            res = re.search("(PUT_LOG\()(.*)(\)\;)", line)
            for segment in res.group(2).split(", "):
                with open(file_out, "a+") as f_out:
                    f_out.write(segment+"\r")

extract_lines()

Comment: @EOL: The `print >>f_out, segment` syntax does work in Python 2 but seems to have been removed in Python 3. It doesn't seem to work for me, please correct me if I'm wrong though~
@Manu: The above code should do exactly that, or does your file_in contain other strings aside from `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG`, `CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD`? This seems contradictory to what you outlined as your objective in your initial post though as you say you want to  extract `CAPTIVE_RECVD_SIGCHLD`, `CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED`, `LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR` as well.

Comment: So where is the exception, @Manu? You just pasted the code. Which version of Python do you work in?

Comment: [Manoj@localhost Python-3.3.0]$ ./test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test1.py", line 21, in <module>
    extract_lines()
  File "./test1.py", line 17, in extract_lines
    for segment in res.group(2).split(", "):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
exception list

Comment: plz see the above exception

Comment: yes my file_in contains the other string aside like ...                 PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD,1,STRING, cmd);
PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD,1,STRING, cmd);
PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG_ERR, CAPTIVE_EXECUTE_CMD_FAILED,1, STRING, cmd);

Comment: @bossi: The Python 3 version of `print >> f_out, segment` is `print(segment, file=f_out)`.

Comment: still m getting error  here 1 ) os.path.realpath("outfile.txt") 2 )  for segment in res.group(2).split(", "):
dont know what to do ...

Comment: @EOL: Thanks for filling me in - would you prefer this alternative (`print(segment, file=f_out)`) as a more elegant or memory-efficient or for any other reason?

@Manu: I've added a conditional statement that ignores lines in your `in.txt` not containing the search pattern at all - that's what threw an exception.

Comment: Its working fine with hard coded value but i want it dynamically when ever i am hitting those line ..

Comment: inside PUT_LOG there are many parameters ...like                        PUT_LOG(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_NO_RAD_SERVERS, 3, IP_INT,(g_radius_cfg.cfg[rad_idx].primary_auth.ip),IP_INT,                 (g_radius_cfg.cfg[rad_idx].secondary_auth.ip),INT,rad_idx);                                                                             But want only first 2 parameters like LOG_LEVEL_INFO, CAPTIVE_NO_RAD_SERVERS

Comment: @bossi Could you please modify bit in your code so that i can get the exactly result

Comment: @Manu: Maybe you could have formulate your question a bit more precise so users know exactly what it is you would like to know. I'm actually still confused what exactly you need; if it is the first two strings after `PUT_LOG(` that are separated and delimited by a comma then you should easily be able to do that by adding a delimiter into the iteration loop. However, this should be completely unnecessary as my code above already filters given strings. If all that doesn't the smallest bit of sense then I suggest learning the absolute basics of the language before you do anything else.

Comment: @Manu: Updated the code again, it extracts the first two occurrences of a string equal to any one element in the passed list for each line.

Comment: I am getting exception near to print(segment, file=f_out) and in strings_to_filter what should i sent as a parameter

Comment: I can't respond to that unless I see the exception.
Again, are you sure you are running Python 3? This code works flawlessly on `Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17)` (32 as well as 64bit)

Comment: print(segment, file=f_out)  this is the error i am getting
                       ^

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Manoj@localhost Python-3.3.0]$ ./test.py
  File "./test.py", line 16
    print(segment, file=f_out)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Manoj@localhost Python-3.3.0]$

Comment: @bossi: your `with open(file_out, "a+") as f_out:` can be put on the same line as your `with open(file_in) as f_in:`, so that the file is opened only once (there is no need to open it over and over again): `with open(file_in) as f_in, open(file_out, 'a+') as f_out:`.

Comment: @EOL: Very good point, thanks for the tip; I wasn't aware that expressions can be chained-up in a `with`-statements.